# How can I conditionally pass an argument from a POSIX shell script?

Tags: shell-script, posix, arguments

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Noise $1"
echo "Enhancement $2"
for snr in 0 5 10 15 20 25
do
  python evaluate.py --noise $1 --snr 25 --iterations 1250 --enhancement $2
done
```

If `$2` is not specified, I don't want to pass the `--enhancement $2` argument to my python script. How would I do that?

Comment: is it a copy/paste typo or are you not using `snr` inside for loop ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `--snr "$snr"`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Modifying your original script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "Noise $1"
echo "Enhancement $2"
for snr in 0 5 10 15 20 25
do
  python evaluate.py --noise "$1" --snr "$snr" --iterations 1250 ${2:+--enhancement "$2"}
done
```

[The standard parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) `${var:+word}` will expand to `word` if the variable `var` is set and not empty.  In the code above, we use it to add `--enhancement "$2"` to the command if `$2` is available and not empty.

I've also taken the liberty to assume that what you are giving to `--snr` as an option-argument should be the loop variable's value.

---

My personal touch on the code (mostly just using `printf` rather than `echo`, avoiding long lines, and giving the code a bit more air):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

printf 'Noise %s\n' "$1"
printf 'Enhancement %s\n' "$2"

for snr in 0 5 10 15 20 25; do
    python evaluate.py \
        --noise "$1" \
        --snr "$snr" \
        --iterations 1250 \
        ${2:+--enhancement "$2"}
done
```

---

As mosvy points out in comments below: If your `/bin/sh` happens to be the `dash` shell, or some other shell that does not properly reset `IFS` as a new shell session starts (this is required by POSIX), and if you have, for one reason or other, exported `IFS` and given it a non-default value, then you may want to use `unset IFS` at the top of the above script.

Do that whenever you have fixed *all other issues that exporting `IFS` doubtlessly have raised* (don't export `IFS`).

Comment: You should also make sure `IFS` is at its default value. But a gotcha of this is that it will treat an _empty_ `$2` argument just like no argument at all. And `${2+... "$2"}` instead of `${2:+... "$2"}` will not cope with that either (as I had foolishly assumed minutes ago)

Comment: @mosvy Thanks. The shell will set `IFS` to the correct value, and the script is not changing it. As for the issue with `$2`, I'm assuming that an empty value is not something the user will want to pass on with the `--enhancement` long option.

Comment: "The shell will set IFS to the correct value" will it? `IFS=, sh -c 'v=a,b; echo $v'` will print `a b` with the default `/bin/sh` on debian. As a matter of practicality, the OP could ... do the whole thing in python instead of bash.

Comment: @mosvy I'd consider that a bug in `dash` as POSIX actually says "The shell shall set IFS to <space> <tab> <newline> when it is invoked."

Comment: It's fixed in newer versions of `dash`, but that doesn't matter: it will take a while until eg. debian 10 gets eol'ed. And people copy shell snippets around, without regard whether they're intended to work as a standalone script. As it stands, your answer is broken: it should _both_ explicitly unset `IFS` and also mention the empty `$2` gotcha.

Comment: @mosvy The thing about `$2` is already mentioned.

Answer (score 15):

On a minimal POSIX shell, that does not support any arrays, you can just manipulate the positional argument list with `set` command. Just before the `for` loop you can do

```
if [ -z "$2" ]; then
    set -- --noise "$1" --snr 25 --iterations 1250
else
    set -- --noise "$1" --snr 25 --iterations 1250 --enhancement "$2"
fi
```

and now run your for loop as

```
for snr in 0 5 10 15 20 25; do
    python evaluate.py "$@"
done
```

If your shell supports array bourne again shell `bash`, `zsh` or other, you can just use an array

```
argv=(--noise "$1" --snr 25 --iterations 1250)

if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
    argv+=( --enhancement "$2" )
fi
```

and now call the script as

```
python evaluate.py "${argv[@]}"
```

As pointed in the comments, you are *not* using the actual value of `snr` value from the for loop. Use the value as `$snr` where applicable in the script arguments, in which case you might need to move the logic of constructing the argument list inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Build the argument in a variable based on the input:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
echo "Noise $1"
echo "Enhancement $2"

if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
   enhance=""
else
   enhance="--enhancement $2"
fi

for snr in 0 5 10 15 20 25
do
  python evaluate.py --noise $1 --snr "$snr" --iterations 1250 $enhance
done
```

(Also includes the correction of the loop variable in the body of the loop)

Comment: that's bad; passing a second argument like `*` or `3000 foo` will break the script.

Comment: No, the script would function the same as the OP's script in those cases.

Comment: ie it will malfunction in the same way

Comment: ie it doesn't receive such values for the second argument.

Comment: Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Unquoted expansions like `$enhance` are affected by the IFS value. Try setting IFS to `IFS=' en'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a single line by using command substitution

```
  python evaluate.py --noise $1 --snr 25 --iterations 1250 $(test -n "$2" && echo --enhancement "$2")
```

Comment: This fails if the value of `$2` can be subject to word-splitting/pathname expansion after the command substation completes.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make a variable expansion disappear is by having the expansion expand to an empty value when that expansion is unquoted.

```
$ unset a; b=''; c=set
$ printf '<%s> ' unquoted $a $b quoted "$a" "$b" val $c "$c"; echo
<unquoted> <quoted> <> <> <val> <s> <t> <set>
```

Both unset and empty values of a variable (`a` and `b`) disappear (as arguments) when unquoted. Both are retained when quoted.

Furthermore, even spaces (or any character) will disappear if included in IFS.

```
$ IFS=' '
$ unset a; b=' '; c='  set  '
$ printf '<%s> ' unquoted $a $b quoted "$a" "$b" val $c "$c"; echo
<unquoted> <quoted> <> < > <val> <set> <  set  >
```

In fact, an IFS that contains characters in the value to expand (unquoted) will separate arguments.

```
$ IFS='e '
$ $ printf '<%s> ' unquoted $a $b quoted "$a" "$b" val $c "$c"; echo
<unquoted> <quoted> <> < > <val> <s> <t> <  set  >
```

Note the two arguments `<s>` and `<t>` which resulted from expanding the value `set` when IFS contained `e`.

So, we need an unquoted expansion of unset or empty values which becomes a quoted expansion of the value when there is a value to expand:

```
${var:+"$var"}
```

Description:

```
${             # starts an un-quoted variable expansion
  var          # name of variable to expand
     :         # also replace if var is null
      +        # use what follows if is not unset (nor null)
       "$var"  # a quoted variable expansion.
             } # end of expansion.

# In short: expand "$var" if it has a value, $var otherwise.
```

We can then use `$1` value to either disappear it or expand it

```
echo ${1:+"--noise"} ${1:+"$1"}
```

The line above will either print **two** separate arguments (not affected by IFS) if `$1` has some (not null) value or nothing if `$1` is empty or unset.

The script will become:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Noise $1"
echo "Enhancement $2"

for    snr in 0 5 10 15 20 25
do     python evaluate.py \
         ${1:+"--noise"} ${1:+"$1"} \
         --snr "$snr" \
         --iterations 1250 \
         ${2:+"--enhancement"} ${2:+"$2"}
done
```

This solution is not affected by the value of IFS