# Is there a bash mode that automatically quotes parameter expansion?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script called `render.sh` that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ -f "${ENVIRONMENT}.yaml" ]]; then
  ENV_YAML="-f ${ENVIRONMENT}.yaml"
fi

set -x
helm3 template "$SERVICE_NAME" . --namespace="$NAMESPACE" \
  ${ENV_YAML:-} \
  --set environment="$ENVIRONMENT"
```

It's sourced in a larger script twice:

```
SERVICE_NAME=a
NAMESPACE=b
ENVIRONMENT=foo
source render.sh

# other code

SERVICE_NAME=a
NAMESPACE=b
ENVIRONMENT=bar
source render.sh
```

The output looks like this:

```
++ helm3 template a . --namespace=b -f foo.yaml --set environment=foo
...
++ helm3 template a . --namespace=b '-f bar.yaml' --set environment=bar
```

In the second execution, something is adding quotes. I know bash has a few different ways of automatically adding quotes like `${VAR@Q}` and `"$@"`, but none of them seem to be in use.

Is there a mode in bash that would automatically add quotes during parameter expansion?

Comment: If you want `-f` and `${ENVIRONMENT}.yaml` to be treated as separate arguments, you should probably be using an array rather than a simple string assignment. See for example [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: I could not reproduce on my machine. However this code might be buggy: if the `.yaml` file does not exist, it will use the previous one, which may be what you want, or not...

Comment: Good tip on the array syntax! I am trying to avoid changing the script in this case, so I'm still curious about what could cause the change in how bash expands the parameters between the two runs

Comment: or [How can I conditionally pass an argument from a POSIX shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/562870/170373)

Comment: Is something modifying `IFS` in between? If it's changed so that it doesn't contain the space, the value from `${ENV_YAML:-}` wouldn't be split.

Comment: Note that it's not about "adding quotes" as such, but about not splitting the value. (Bash's `set -x` output does include quotes so that the output is aligns with shell syntax and is unambiguous, though.) The quotes produced by `${VAR@Q}` are actually there in the value, while `"$@"` can be said to be similar to `"$1" "$2"` but is probably better thought of as just giving the positional parameters as separate fields/arguments without other changes or additions.

Comment: Consider e.g. `VAR="abc def"; set -- uvw xyz; printf "<%s>\n" "${VAR@Q}" "$@"`, where `<'abc def'>` outputs with quotes, but `<uvw>`, `<xyz>` don't.

Comment: Also I'm not sure the `:-` in `${ENV_YAML:-}` does much, as it only tells the shell to use the empty string if the variable value is the empty string (or unset).